# in angular 5 how to make splash screen till the child component load all images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, user-experience

I'm using angular 5 for displaying pages that have a lot of images with high res, and it takes too long to load.
What I want to do is to make a **splash screen**, a div that will cover the full screen, and after all the images finish loading it will disappear.
How and where do I implement this in angular 5?

```
window.onload = someFunction; // is not working well
```

**page.component.html**:

```
<div id="page" class="page">
<div id="splash"></div>
<div id="home-page">
    <div class="container  d-none d-lg-block">
        <img src="assets/images/home/line_with_bird.png" alt="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 ad-paper">
                <img src="assets/images/home/paper.png" class="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <img id="arrow-word" src="assets/images/arrow_word.png" alt="">
                <img id="ladder" src="assets/images/ladderLong.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 offset-1 c2">
                <div id="window"></div>
                <div class="smicos">
                    <app-socialmedia style="width: 641px;"></app-socialmedia>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

page.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    function splash() {
        console.log('tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt');
        document.getElementById('splash').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('window').classList.add('window-animation');
    }

    window.onload = splash;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are doing

Comment: @bugs here it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not hide your splash screen on `ngOnInit`. Instead do this:

Keep count of images you are showing in controller.

totalImages = 20;

Keep a load handler on each image;

```
<img (load)='checkAllLoaded()'>
```

In `checkAllLoaded` function, check if all images are loaded:

```
checkAllLoaded() {
  this.totalImages = this.totalImages - 1;
  if(this.totalImages === 0) {
     document.getElementById('splash').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('window').classList.add('window-animation');
  }
}
```

Comment: i think its not that, the images load slowly.. this is the problem.

Comment: Yes my friend, even if images load slowly, the load function will not be called till image is loaded completely

Comment: that works very fine with <img /> but what about the background images?

Comment: you can add all the background images also as img tags, and add display:none; to them. That way, you can track when those are loaded plus still use them as background images via css

Comment: can i use (load) on a div? what if i used it in <div id="home-page">?

Comment: no, load cannot be used on div. It is supposed to be added to elements which will require network

Comment: please mark it as answer and upvote it if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Set a div with *ngIf on a property which will turn to true only when the image is loaded.

```
<div class="splash" *ngIf="!loaded"></div>
<img [src]="img" (load)='loaded=true'>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbfpky)